# What's the pythonic way to package a web app with a generation step?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, setuptools, webpack

I have a Python-based web app that I'm trying to package as a **setuptools** package so that it can be installed using `pip` and/or `python setup.py xxxxx`. This web app also contains static files for a React front end. I use **webpack** (and therefore **node.js**) to generate the JavaScript bundle for the website. I'm trying to figure out the most pythonic way to package this. From googling around a bit, I found [`nodeenv`](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv) which seems relevant.

Ideally, I would like this package to have the following traits:

- When installed with `pip install` or `python setup.py install` it *should not* install `node` and `webpack`, but the installed package *should* include the webpack output.
- The `webpack`-generated output should *not* need to be checked into the source repo. (i.e. it will need to be generated at some point or another in the packaging process.)
- When the package is set up for development via `pip install -e` or `python setup.py develop`, it *should* install `node` and `webpack` (I suspect the aforementioned `nodeenv` will be useful in this regard.) It should also *run* `webpack` at this time, so that afterwards, the `webpack`-generated content exists.
- If it were easy, it would also be cool if `webpack` could be started in "watch" mode when the virtualenv is activated, and stopped when it's deactivated (but this is *totally* a stretch goal.)

My hunch, given these requirements, is that I will need to subclass the `sdist` command to cause the webpack output to be generated at source distribution generation time. I'm also guessing I'll need to subclass the `develop` command to inject the development-only requirements.

It seems like this is a bridge that someone must have crossed before. Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off splitting these concerns into different build steps, if we disect your process a bit, these steps come up (assuming that `node`, `npm` and the `virtualenv` are already installed on your box)

1. Install the required python modules in the local virtualenv.
2. Install webpack and the npm modules needed to run the webpack script.
3. Run the webpack config so your static assets will be compiled locally.

Each of these steps represent a command that can end up in a **Makefile** or just a simple shell script for example (or use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) if you want to stick with python) so you would end up with the following commands:

- `python-requirements`
- `node-requirements`
- `build-static`
- `build` -> `python-requirements`, `node-requirements`, `build-static`

Now you can run these commands at will! If you're deploying you would run `build` for example, which will run each step in succession.

Comment: The solution I'm trying to replace is this kind of thing. I was really hoping I could get it captured all in one unit. Since asking, I've actually gotten it working as described in my question (subclassing `install`, `sdist` and `develop`), but wanted to see if there was any existing guidance that had escaped my googling. `distutils` and `setuptools` have so much flexibility (and at the same time, so many holes), it's often tough to know if you're doing things the "right" way.

Comment: It's really tricky to actually proper package a python app, the `--relocatable` flag in virtualenv is buggy and considered deprecated. Have a look at docker for a true deployable wrapper.

Comment: The basic idea here is that this gets `pip install`ed from a private PyPi server into a docker container at `docker build` time, so I'm familiar. If nothing else, thanks for confirming that this is tricky... :)

Answer (score 1):

We're not the same deployment system but seek the same sort of thing: no need for node on production, but build with webpack for the final deployment.  We're using docker to run up a temporal build machine...

The builder installs all the distribution packages it needs, then checks out the code, calls `setup.py` to build itself, runs myriad tests, and finally deploys the build dir to prod.

1. So I've left it up to the docker's config to ensure that `nodejs` and `npm` are installed by adding `curl... && apt-get` etc. to the `Dockerfile`.
2. I've subclassed the `sdist` and modified the `run` command to just run `npm install` and `webpack` on the commandline when it runs.

So in `setup.py`

```
setup(
    name='myapp',
    ...
    cmdclass={'sdist': MySdistCommand}
    ...)
```

Then `MySdistCommand` is

```
from setuptools.command.sdist import sdist

class MySdistCommand(sdist):
   def run(self):
       import subprocess
       subprocess.check_call(['npm', 'install'])
       subprocess.check_call(['./node_modules/.bin/webpack', '-p'])
       sdist.run(self)
```

Which seems to work so far.  I'll let you know if quirks appear when we try to deploy it to prod (via a rather contorted docker+puppet system). I'm not sure what directory it will find itself in when it tries to run for real, but it works in dev. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the (incredibly late) answer. But I ran into this same problem, and solved it with an entry point, something like [this](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/). Adding an entry point allows us to add a script that will be in the same folder as a webpack config that you might have.

As a result, you can just check in the entry point, whether a build has occurred and build if it hasn't :) Alternatively, if you must build when you run `setup.py`, you can include two functions in your entry point, and just run the setup function on your `setup.py install develop` step and then use a custom build step to perform an `npm install` or something similar.

The main part you need is:

```
entry_points={
    "console_scripts": [
        "mywebpack=script_build:main",
    ]
},
```

My script looks something like

```
from os.path import exists, dirname, join
from subprocess import Popen
import sys


def main():

    # Find the path of the script
    path = dirname(__file__)

    # Get the arguments that should pass to webpack
    args = sys.argv[1:]

    # Call webpack with the arguments passed to this program
    webpack_invocation = join(path, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'webpack')
    webpack_command = [webpack_invocation] + args
    process = Popen(webpack_invocation, cwd=path, shell=True)
    process.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then you can use this from the console with

```
mywebpack <options>
```

This will guarantee that it uses a locally installed version of webpack :)
Hope that helps!